# Permutations in $S_9$ with length $4,3,2$.

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

How many permutations in $S_9$ have one cycle of length $4$, one of length $3$, and one of
length $2$?

My attempt so far is: ${9 \choose 4}*{5 \choose 3}*{2 \choose 2}$, which is the way to choose elements in each cycle but then how do I find the numbers ways that the elements can give distinct cycles? Because ${9 \choose 4}*{5 \choose 3}*{2 \choose 2}=1260$ and think the answer should be a lot higher!

If anyone can help me understand what I need to multiply and *why*!

Thank you!

Comment: Cf. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158621/how-many-elements-of-order-4-in-s-7/3158654#3158654); did you mean $\dfrac{9!}{4!}\dfrac14...?$

Comment: The correct answer is meant to be $15120$

Comment: It’s $\dfrac{9!}{5!4}\dfrac{5!}{2!3}$ ; I typed $4!$ but meant $5!$ in my previous comment

Comment: How did you get this? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: See my explanation in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the cycle of length $4$, you have $9$ choices for the first element, $8$ for the second, $7$ for the third, and $6$ for the fourth.  But you have to divide by $4$ because for example $(1234)=(2341)$.

For the cycle of length $3$ you then have $5$ choices for the first element, $4$ for the second, and $3$ for the third; divide by $3$ because there are three ways to represent the same cycle.

Once you have chosen the cycles of length $4$ and $3$, the cycle of length $2$ is uniquely determined.  (There are two possibilities for the first element, but the cycle is the same no matter which of the remaining two elements is written first.)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You’re welcome @Jamesodare,   and thanks for the prompt acceptance!   Note that for example $(6789)$ and $(6879)$ are different cycles, so you want $\frac{9!}{5!}$, not $\binom 95$; I think that’s why the answer is a lot higher than what you calculated